# sum of 50+25+12.5....

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Madan completes half of his work on Monday. He does half of what was left on Tuesday and so on. He followed this pattern for one week. About how much of the work would he have completed during the week? 69%/79%/89%/99%

50+25+12.5+6>89, so answer is 99%.

but i wish somebody could provide the complete answer to it without having to calculate each day's work percent.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula for the general formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$a+ar+\ldots +ar^{n-1}=a\dfrac{1-r^{n}}{1-r}$$

Here $a=50$, $r=\frac{1}{2}$ and $n=4$ (if you are thinking of four days, $7$ if it concerns a week)

Comment: Shouldn't n be 7?

Comment: @Ramit: thank you, I repaired. Personally I prefer a workweek of $4$ days :-).

Answer (score 1):

A quicker way is to think : What percentage did he not do?

After one day he didn't do 50%.

... After n days he didn't do $\frac{100}{2^n}$% of the homework.

So Friday, that's 4 days, he didn't do $\frac{100}{2^4} = 6.25$

Now, if you assume a week is seven days (until the following Monday), you get $\frac{100}{2^7} \approx 1$ of the homework hasn't been done.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

Day 1:

```
50 = 100 - 50
```

Day 2:

```
50 + 25 = 100 - 25
```

Day 3:

```
50 + 25 + 12.5 = 100 - 12.5
```

Day 4:

```
50 + 25 + 12.5 + 6.725 = 100 - 6.725
```